# edeliver with distillery: how to setup `start` command to use systemctl

Tags: elixir, edeliver, distillery

I am deploying the Elixir project to remote using [`edeliver`](https://github.com/edeliver/edeliver) backed up by [`distillery`](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery).

I also successfully created the `systemd.service` file that starts, stops, restarts etc the release from the command line.

But the `mix edeliver start production` command seems to run the release bypassing `systemd`, by plain old good `bin/my_app start` shell command. What I want is to use `systemd` always, even with hot uploads, since it (unlike `upstart`) does provide `reload` functionality.

I can not find what and whom am I to tell to use `systemd` to [re]start the release. Should it be `delivery` strategy? Something else? I understand this question is not a good fit for SO, but I am just lost.

So: can I force `edeliver` over `distillery` to use `systemd` to start the release? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I will post it here. I had overcome the issue with a nasty kludge. I have a `release.sh` script that contains few subsequent `build`, `deploy` and `ping` commands. So I did the following:

```
# mix edeliver restart production

for host in `cat .deliver/config | grep PRODUCTION_HOSTS | cut -d '=' -f 2 | sed -e 's/"//g'`
do
  echo "Restarting the remote [$host]..."
  echo `ssh rates-injector@$host sudo systemctl restart rates_injector.service`
done
echo "Likely restarted."
```

Basically, I manually issue the `restart` command for `systemctl`, getting production hosts list from the `.deliver/config` file.